# Pymongo bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode Object when read from file

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I have a `csv` file with a header row and 100k entries in it.

I am using `python` in `pycharm` IDE and `conda` as python interpreter. `conda` suppies `pymongo-3.4.0` as `mongo-driver`.

I parse my `csv` file and save it as `json`n file on disk, and then iterate over the `json` file to insert the `json` objects in the `mongo` database.

JSON looks like this:

```
{
  a1 : {'name': 702104534, type='Single' }
  a2 : {'name': 702104535, type='Single' }
  a3 : {'name': 702104536, type='Married' }
}
```

Python Code:

```
import pymongo
import pickle

with open('my_json_file.json', 'rb') as in_file:
    person_json = pickle.load(in_file)

conn = pymongo.MonogClient('localhost','27017')
db = conn['db']
coll = db['coll']

persons = person_json.keys()
for person in persons:
    coll.insert_one(person_json[person])
```

Throughs the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PyCharmWorkSpace/LCR/json2mongo.py", line 109, in <module>
    data2mongo()
File "C:/PyCharmWorkSpace/LCR/json2mongo.py", line 89, in data2mongo
    coll.insert_one(json_str)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 657, in insert_one
    bypass_doc_val=bypass_document_validation),
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 562, in _insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, op_id, bypass_doc_val)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 543, in _insert_one
    check_keys=check_keys)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 424, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 552, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise error
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 419, in command
    collation=collation)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 94, in command
    None, codec_options, check_keys)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 702104534
```

However, same works, if the json string is a variable

Python Code:

```
import pymongo

conn = pymongo.MonogClient('localhost','27017')
db = conn['db']
coll = db['coll']

person = {'name': 702104534, 'type'='Single' }
coll.insert_one(person)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you `print(type(person_json[person]['name']))`

Comment: @arthur `<class 'numpy.int32'>`, also tried to type cast the value using `bson.int64.Int64(702104534)`, then the error changes to `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 0`

Comment: Any recommended solution, @arthur???

Comment: did you try casting with `int()` instead of `bson.int64.Int64()` ?

Comment: Yeah, when I do `bson.int64.Int64()` the error changes to `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 0`

Comment: I understand but try with `int()`, not with `bson.int64.Int64()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172907/discussion-between-arthur-and-yash).

Comment: Same error: `Cannot encode object: 0`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `pymongo` has some run time type-casting compatibility issues when `json` is dynamically generated or read from a disk-based file, when the `json` string is *inserted* to `mongodb` using either of insert methods, such as `insert` or `insert_one` or `insert_many`.

I was able to insert the `json` objects to the `mongodb` by associating standard python type casting.

Comment: can u elaborate this